# Does anyone have a French translation of the AG-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm wondering if someone would already have done this work, I'm looking for the french version of the AG-Grid localisation. I can see the values here : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-localisation/

But I'm sure someone already has the french values translated, does anyone know where I can find them ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some examples on github that you may be interested in: [1](https://github.com/OussamaELAMRANI/DaoApp/blob/dda7860ee8757f892eab22515b1043933ec9012c/resources/js/lang/agGrid/index.js), [2](https://github.com/BBj-Plugins/BBjGridExWidget/blob/355aba449557629b84b438afcceccb23a24a7503/langs/fr_FR.json)

My method is to find a somewhat unique key of the [`localeText`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-localisation/#using-localetext) object, in this case `totalAndFilteredRows` and search it on [github](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=totalAndFilteredRows&type=Code). There are a lot of examples from many languages but unfortunately there is no way to search for a specific language that I know of.

Comment: Excellent method to find a reference! Thanks for the extra tip! The 2 you found are pretty good, a good start for sure and I might tweak some.